# Collapsible containers overlap when expanding

Tags: app.diagrams.net

So I have 2 collapsible containers. Is there a way to keep them from overlapping when expanded? As in "push" the other container to make room for the one being expanded.

Here are the 2 containers:

[image]

Here is what I get when I expand the top one:

[image]

Here is what I would like to happen when I expand the top one:

[image]

Is this possible with draw.io?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unfortunately it is not possible at the moment.

Regards,